# How to solve System.Data.SQLite File Not Found Exception in Visual basic 2013 program on client computer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

[I know this question has been asked many times on Stackoverflow itself, but I couldn't find any answer working for me, so asking a separate question.]

I made a program in visual basic 2013, which uses SQLite database. I installed SQLite from NuGet Package Manager. It works fine on my development machine (windows 8.1), but it **throws `FileNotFoundException`  for `System.Data.SQLite.dll` file on  non-development computers** (most of them are running windows 7).

I have set solution platform to `x86` only.

I have installed .net 4.5.1 on all computers (same as my development one)

I have tried -

- Project -> References -> System.Data.SQLite -> Set Copy Local to True
  (it includes the mentioned dll but exception is still thrown)
- Manually copy-pasting specified dll (along with & without other dlls
  from `SQLite.NET\bin\` and `System.Data.SQLite\2013\bin\` folders)
  into application folder
- Tried manually registering dll by `regserver32` but it didn't get
  register

Complete error text is (if it helps) -

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Medical_MCQs.Functions' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Medical_MCQs.Functions..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Medical_MCQs.Functions.CheckDatabase()
   at Medical_MCQs.Medical_MCQs.MedicalStudy_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\VisualStudioProjects\Medical MCQs\Medical MCQs\MedicalStudy.vb:line 4
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Medical MCQs
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/test/app/Medical%20MCQs.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50938.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: What NuGet Package are you using?

Comment: @DavidSdot it's named "System.Data.SQlite(x86/x64)" (and some more automatically installed with it) in NuGet Package

Comment: Is there a folder in you project called x86 that includes SQLite.Interop.dll ?

Comment: @DavidSdot yes it's there in x86 folder

Comment: `Manually copy-pasting specified dll` It's a long shot, but try pasting the DLL in your `Windows/` directory.

Comment: Check your Project Settings > Publish > Application Files. SQLite.Interop.dll should show as "Include (Auto)".

Comment: @DavidSdot thanks. For some reasons, Interop.dll was not automatically included initially. After your mention, I set it to include (auto) and i got it work (i think, need to test on some more computers for final result).